# TCP connection - client sending FIN in middle of communication

Tags: azure, tcp, firewall

I have azure VM which act as a TCP server (java program which listen on a port). TCP client (ncat) sits in corporate network. There is a corporate firewall in between. Client initiates a connection with server  by sending message and after that server keeps sending the one line message to client at every 3 second. client do receive 3 or 4 messages but after that it stops receiving any message. There is no exception at server side. When client and server both are in corporate network, i don't experience this issue. The wire shark capture is below. I don't understand why client is sending FIN (highlighted in yellow) in between. Any suggestions please.

[image: Wireshark Capture]

Comment: Because it is closing the connection, or shutting it down for output. This is not a mystery.

Comment: Then why it is not happening when both client and server are on corporate network

Comment: Because it isn't closing the connection or shutting it down for output. It is also possible that an intervening router is dropping the connection in the first case. You're expecting a lot asking about the behaviour of unknown software. I don't know what kind of answer would satisfy you. Off topic.

Comment: I don't think it is a Off topic. I don't understand what do you mean by shutting it down for output. I have a application which was hosted on corporate network and it used to work fine when client was also in corporate network. Now my application migrated to azure VM and it started giving trouble. So i need to understand what could be the possible solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the tcp-halfclose-timer value in firewall between Azure and Corporate network. It was set to 10 second, so once FIN is sent from client, after 10 second server was not able to send any messages to client as firewall was closing the half closed connection after 10 second. The value is changed to 1 hour and after that the issue got resolved.

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar issue, but one thing is still unclear to me from your answer. I understand that the solution was to increase the tcp-halfclose-timer value, but why did the client send the FIN packet in the first place?